# PostgreSQL - how to generate an array containing column name and column data...?

Tags: postgresql, array, data-dictionary

I'd like to create a dictionary - an array - from a simple query, to include column names in output.

IE, I'd like to turn this:

```
SELECT id, last, first FROM names;

  id | last     | first        
-----+----------+-------------------------
001  | Smith    | John
```

into:

```
{ "id": "001","last": "Smith", "first": "John" }
```

Yes, bonus points for the quotes and colons! Ha!

We do have this very interesting catalog function, which will return all column names into an array.

```
SELECT array_agg(column_name::TEXT) 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'people';
```

How to aggregate (couldn't help myself) that into a regular query?

Answer (score 1):

The first one can be done using a [JSON function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
select to_jsonb(n)
from names n;
```

I have no idea what you want to achieve with the second query.

Comment: second box is not a query, it's the intended result. Yes, am aware of the jsonb structure, but how to add the column name elements? There's the rub!

Comment: My query will return exactly what you want: https://rextester.com/TAFU29113 And I was not referring to the second "box", but to the second _query_ (the one on information schema)

Answer (score 0):

Tks, a_horse_with_no_name, you put me on the right track (clearly needed to do a bit more studying here!)

to_jsonb() doesn't get me all the way there; row_to_json() was the winner:

```
# SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (SELECT SELECT id, last, first FROM names WHERE id = '001') t;
```

Comment: There is no difference between the result of `to_jsonb()` and `row_to_json()` (except the data type that is)